# Turning off refresh on a Visual C++ Chart control

Tags: .net, visual-c++, charts, c++-cli

I apologize if this is an ignorant question. It seems it should be trivial, yet I can't find a solution that works.

I have a Chart control in a Visual C++ 2010 form. I'm reading a bunch of data out of a form, doing some computation, then plotting the results. I'm using AddXY to add the data, and it works fine.

However, every time I call AddXY, it refreshes the chart. With a large data set, I'd prefer that it suspend redraws until all the data is added, then resume redraws. I don't need to watch the line crawl across the screen, and it slows the load down substantially. I would think this would be simple.

Using "SuspendLayout" on the control or the form didn't seem to affect it. The Chart class does not have a BeginUpdate and EndUpdate like some other controls do. This discussion talks about a workaround for flicker-free use, but that is more than I need.

Am I missing something stupid here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataPointCollection` that you are calling `AddXY()` from has the calls that you need. Specifically:

`DataPointCollection.SuspendUpdates()` and `DataPointCollection.ResumeUpdates()`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, although there was a bit of a twist. There seems to be something odd happening with scoping. I was turning off updates, then calling a helper function (all in the same class and namespace) to process and add each point. That didn't work -- the updates kept happening. So I flattened the structure and added the points in the same function that I suspended the updates, and it worked. Thanks!